# Leaving a for loop when input is successful

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how you leave a for loop if the input is successful, the user will have 3 attempts to enter a number above 0. Its working for them being unsuccessful but its still making me enter the value 3 times even if a correct number is inputted.

```
for (var attempts = 3; attempts--;) {
    var input = window.prompt("Please enter a number");
    if ( input < 0) {
        document.write("Try Again");
    }
}
document.write("Grand");
```

Comment: add an `else` containing a `break` under your `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems with your code:

1. You have no `else` statement.  If they don't enter the correct code it doesn't process anything *else* conditionally.  It will *always* process the "Grand" output regardless of input.
2. The condition of `< 0` isn't what you want.  If they enter `0` it would still pass the check and say "Try Again"
3. The answer to your actual question, simply add a break in the (missing) `else` statement.

Try this:

```
<script>
for (var attempts = 1; attempts <= 3; attempts++) {
  var input = window.prompt("Please enter a number");
  if (input <= 0) {
    if (attempts == 3) {
       //this is the 3rd failure 
       document.write("You have failed 3 times!");
       break;
    } else {
       //this is for the 1st and second failures
       document.write("Try Again<br>");
    }
  } else {
    document.write("Grand");
    break;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. After you input a positive number, it asks again for another.

Comment: Oops, misread the question.  I thought the "correct" answer was 0. I'll update, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. However 1 more thing. When a negative number is inputted 3 times, try again is outputted 3 times to the screen. I know this because of the loop however how do I only output it once or instead "unsuccessful" or something like that

Comment: So you want it to say "Try again" on the first failure but something different on the next two?

Comment: How do I output something on the screen when they entered a negative number 3 times. I've changed my first document.write to an alert saying try again.

Comment: But only once!! Not 3 times from the loop!

Comment: Okay, my updated answer will tell them to try again twice then after the 3rd incorrect entry it will say "You failed 3 times".  This probably should have been a separate question, but that's okay.  Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Fixed it. Your code is still wrong. Says failed after 1 try!!

Comment: It was missing a simicolon.  I tested it this time and it works.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can leave a loop with a `break` statement.

```
for (var attempts = 3; attempts > 0; attempts--) {
    var input = window.prompt("Please enter a number");
    if ( input < 0) {
        if(attempts > 1){
            document.write("Try Again");    
        }else{
            document.write("No more attempts!");
        }

    }else{
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest yet however, when a negative number is inputted 3 times. "Try again" is outputted 3 times to the screen.

Comment: Updated it, this now only prints "Try again" two times. If the user inputs a negative number for the third time the program just without displaying anything.

Comment: Now it also prints a message after the last failed attempt.

Comment: Ok. You have syntax error in your for loop - var attempts = 3; attempts > 0  attempts--;

Comment: And also its not working - Nothing displayed when positive number is entered.

Comment: And try again printed twice screen when number incorrectly typed in 3 times

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, here is one:

```
var attempts = 3, valid_input = false, input;

while (attempts > 0 && valid_input === false) {
    input = parseInt(window.prompt("Please enter a number"), 10);
    if (input <= 0) {
        alert("Try Again");
    } else {
        valid_input = true;
    }
}
if (valid_input === true) {
    document.write("Grand");
} else {
    document.write("Failed 3 times");
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `attempts--;`?